# Json Keys Are Undefined When Using Them From Script Tag

Tags: javascript, json

I've been trying to load certain Json with Ajax GET request and then parsing it.

However when trying to access the Json key from HTML script tag it was undefined.

In order to debug this issue, I logged all the keys of Json in console as well as the Json itself. Therefore i utilized this function:

```
function getInv() {
    $.get( "/inventory/", function( data ) {
      var invList = data.split(",, "); // Explanation is below
      console.log(invList[0]) // Just testing with first object
      console.log(Object.keys(invList[0]));
    });
}
getInv();
```

**Purpose of** **data.split(",, "):**

Since my backend script uses different programming language, I had to interpret it to the one suitable for Javascript.
There also were multiple Json objects, So i separated them with `",, "` and then split them in Javascript in order to create a list of Json objects.

After calling the function, Following output was present:

[image]

Although the interesting part is that after pasting Json object in console like this:

[image]

This was the output:

[image]

So basically, in script tag, i was unable to access object's keys, although once i used it manually in console, all keys could be accessed.

What could be the purpose behind this? It seems quite strange that different outputs are given. Perhaps `invList[0]` is not Json object at all in the script tag? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: _"There also were multiple Json objects, So i separated them with ",, ""..._ What??

Comment: In your backend script, can't you put all the objects in an array and then convert that array to JSON, instead of separating them with `,,`?

Comment: @Andy Like `JSON.stringify(foo) + ',,' + JSON.stringify(bar) + ',,' + JSON.stringify(xxx)`

Comment: Ha. Yes, I knew what he was doing. I was using _What??_ to mean _WTF??_ :)

Comment: Good to know I can break your backend by typing the name `,, `.

Comment: The output (in the console) of `console.log(invList[0])` is clearly a string.

Comment: Guys, In python (backend language) i made up list of Json objects, and then since Javascript Array and Python list is different, I separate Json objects with ",, " in backend, However ",, " could be anything else though as long as it marks difference between each object. Since objects are seperated with ",, ", i can simply convert python list to javascript array with split function. (Basically, ",, " is just a mark between each object to easily create array in Javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.split()` returns an array of strings, not objects. You need to use `JSON.parse()` to parse the JSON string to the corresponding objects.

```
function getInv() {
    $.get( "/inventory/", function( data ) {
      var invList = data.split(",, "); 
      console.log(invList[0]) // Just testing with first object
      var obj = JSON.parse(invList[0]);
      console.log(Object.keys(obj));
    });
}
```

You can use `.map()` to parse all of them, then you'll get an array of objects like you were expecting:

```
var invList = data.split(",, ").map(JSON.parse);
```